# environment.rb contents when migrating from Rails 2 to Rails 3

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-3-upgrade

I'm updating an application from rails 2.3 to rails 3.1, and I'm new to rails. I followed the RailsCast and got some idea. Somebody please help me for where to place my old environment variables. These are the four pieces of code in my old `environment.rb`

1:

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'development'
```

2:

```
if RUBY_PLATFORM =~ /java/
  require 'rubygems'
  RAILS_CONNECTION_ADAPTERS = %w(jdbc)
end
```

3:

```
CalendarDateSelect.format = :hyphen_ampm
```

4:

```
Mime::Type.register "text/csv", :csv
```

Where do I place this, the new `environment.rb` or `application.rb`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure out the answer, all the configurations must go to the application.rb

Answer (score 2):

3 and 4 in an initializer (config/initializers), i don't think you need 1, and i am not sure about 2, but i think you just need to add `gem 'activerecord-jdbc-adapter'` to your Gemfile. ( i haven't used jruby with rails yet, so i honestly don't know, it's just a guess, because i saw it somewhere )

Answer (score 1):

Don't upgrade. People may not like that answer, but it's not worth the effort to go from 2.3 to 3. Starting from scratch? Maybe use 3, up to you.

Comment: This is the best approach, as things can be pretty messy.  I would start fresh with 3.1, write your tests, and then the code.

Answer (score 1):

This tutorial helped me do what you are trying to do: http://gregmoreno.ca/rails-3-upgrade-part-1-booting-the-application/